# Generate Gateway scenario in Contiki in cooja simulator

Tags: c, contiki, iot

I want to generate scenario where IoT network communicate through ipv6 via Gateway Router natively mean on simulator i don't have real motes to test.

How to make linux communicate to Cooja simulator as a gateway?

Comment: Does this mean that you want to connect linux with the serial port of a simulated mote?

Comment: yes, i want to simulate scenario like linux can communicate to iot network via gateway node

Comment: Well, kfx's answer is what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks i got serial2pty idea about how to use it. for future reference if any tutorial related to learn contiki in deep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `serial2pty` plugin: https://github.com/cmorty/cooja-serial2pty

The plugin creates a virtual serial port (pseudoterminal: PTY). You can then access that PTY as any regular serial port in Linux.

There might be a problem if the port is created dynamically - you won't know the name of the PTY device. So the plugin also includes discovery service functionality. It is a TCP server that returns the name of the PTY.

Here's Python code that can be used to get the name of the PTY using this discovery service:

```
    address = "localhost"
    port = 6100

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.settimeout(3.0)
    sock.connect((address, port))
    data = ""
    while True:
        c = sock.recv(1)
        if c not in ['/', '.'] and not c.isalnum():
            break
        data += c
        if len(data) > 100: break
    sock.close()
    return data
```

Comment: Thanks  kfx. i am confuse about how to make schenario like 10 nodes creating IoT network(let say smart home network of different sensors like light, temp etc) these nodes are connected to internet via one / many gateway node ....so when any request comes for temp/light or data it comes firstly to gateway node then it pass request to IoT network.

Comment: @sagar did you find any solution? I want to do the same!